# Gremlin get a result set of more than one vertex type and different stages of the pipeline

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

I am trying to get a result set that includes vertices at different stages of a gremlin pipeline. For example, considering the following sample graph:

CITY
  name = NY

CAR
  model = Tesla, 
  color = white

CAR
  model = Toyota,
  color = Red

PERSON

```
--lives --> City (NY)
--owns --> Car (Tesla)
name = xyz
gender = male
```

Person

```
--lives --> City (NY)
--owns --> Car (Toyota) 
name = abc
gender = male
```

Person

```
--lives --> City (NY)
--owns --> Car (Tesla)
name = def
gender = female
```

The above graph, since its not very clear contains 3 vertices for three persons, all linked to a single City node and linked to two different car nodes.

How can I write a query in gremlin that returns both the list of male persons living in NY as well the car they own.

I have so far a pipe which does this:

```
GremlinPipeline pipe = new GremlinPipeline(graph.getVerticesOfClass("City"));

pipe.has("name", "NY").in("lives").has("gender", "male")
```

This returns me just the male persons in new york vertices but not their cars as well.

The following returns the cars but not the persons.

```
pipe.has("name", "NY").in("lives").has("gender", "male").out("owns")
```

Is there a good way to get both these vertex types as part of a result of a single query. This is similar to something I would achieve with the traverse query in Orient SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. If you really want to co-mingle the people and cars in a single list you can use the store pipe:

```
list = []
pipe.has("name", "NY").in("lives").has("gender", "male").store(list).out('owns').store(list).iterate()
list
```

If you wish to maintain the relationships between the people and their (perhaps multiple) cars then I recommend creating a map of people to cars:

```
pipe.has("name", "NY").in("lives").has("gender", "male").groupBy{it.name}{it.out('owns')}.cap()
```

Here's a complete class that implements all three approaches in Java using the Tinkerpop graph.

```
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Graph;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.tg.TinkerGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.GremlinPipeline;
import com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.PipesFunction;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Foo
{
  private static final PipesFunction<Vertex, String> NAME_FUNCTION = new PipesFunction<Vertex, String>()
  {
    @Override
    public String compute(Vertex vertex)
    {
      return vertex.getProperty("name");
    }
  };
  private static final PipesFunction<Vertex, Iterable<String>> OWNS_NAME_FUNCTION = new PipesFunction<Vertex, Iterable<String>>()
  {
    @Override
    public Iterable<String> compute(Vertex vertex)
    {
      return new GremlinPipeline(vertex).out("owns").property("name");
    }
  };

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Graph graph = new TinkerGraph();
    Vertex boy1 = graph.addVertex(1);
    Vertex boy2 = graph.addVertex(2);
    Vertex girl = graph.addVertex(3);
    Vertex ny = graph.addVertex(4);
    Vertex toyota = graph.addVertex(5);
    Vertex tesla = graph.addVertex(6);
    boy1.setProperty("type", "Person");
    boy1.setProperty("name", "xyz");
    boy1.setProperty("gender", "male");
    boy2.setProperty("type", "Person");
    boy2.setProperty("name", "abc");
    boy2.setProperty("gender", "male");
    girl.setProperty("type", "Person");
    girl.setProperty("name", "def");
    girl.setProperty("gender", "female");
    ny.setProperty("type", "City");
    ny.setProperty("name", "NY");
    toyota.setProperty("type", "Car");
    toyota.setProperty("name", "toyota");
    toyota.setProperty("color", "red");
    tesla.setProperty("type", "Car");
    tesla.setProperty("name", "tesla");
    toyota.setProperty("color", "white");
    boy1.addEdge("lives", ny);
    boy1.addEdge("owns", tesla);
    boy2.addEdge("lives", ny);
    boy2.addEdge("owns", toyota);
    girl.addEdge("lives", ny);
    girl.addEdge("owns", tesla);

    // Reading a pipe
    GremlinPipeline pipe = new GremlinPipeline(graph.getVertices("type", "City"));
    pipe = pipe.has("name", "NY").in("lives").has("gender", "male");
    for (Object o : pipe)
    {
      System.out.println(o.toString());
    }

    // Reading a list
    List list = new ArrayList();
    pipe = new GremlinPipeline(graph.getVertices("type", "City"));
    pipe.has("name", "NY").in("lives").has("gender", "male").store(list, NAME_FUNCTION).out("owns").store(list, NAME_FUNCTION).iterate();
    System.out.println(list);

    // Reading a map
    pipe = new GremlinPipeline(graph.getVertices("type", "City"));
    Map map = (Map) pipe.has("name", "NY").in("lives").has("gender", "male").groupBy(NAME_FUNCTION, OWNS_NAME_FUNCTION).cap().next();
    System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul. That makes sense. Is there a way I can do this in java too? I see that it does not let me do so with a generic list.

Comment: Not sure where the problems is - there are no closures in Java 7 so you have to implement a PipeFunction. Also, both of my examples do NOT return pipelines, but rather a collection (list or map) that contains the results, which is unfortunate because lazy evaluation is a nice feature of Gremlin.

Comment: Thats really useful Paul. Thanks for the detailed example.